# How to ignore properties based on their type

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to copy an entity framework object to another identical database. The problem is that it tries to copy the lookup tables.

I have tried to exclude them with the `AddGlobalIgnore` and the  `ShouldMapProperty` but it doesn't work. AutoMapper still try to copy those properties.

Here's my code. I would like to ignore the properties that start with "LU"

```
 dynamic newObject= new NewObject();

 MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
 {
     cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
     cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("LU");
     cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => !p.GetType().ToString().StartsWith("LU");
     cfg.ShouldMapField = p => !p.GetType().ToString().StartsWith("LU");
 });
 IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
 newObject = mapper.Map(objectToCopy, objectToCopy.GetType(), newObject.GetType());
```

I did also tried

```
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
   cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
   cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("LU");
   cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => !p.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("LU");
   cfg.ShouldMapField = p => !p.FieldType.Name.StartsWith("LU");
 });
```

and

```
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
   cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
   cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("LU");
   cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => !p.Name.StartsWith("LU");
   cfg.ShouldMapField = p => !p.Name.StartsWith("LU");
});
```

Comment: Wait, why do you have a dynamic object in the mix there?

Comment: @JimmyBogard  
Because `mapper.Map()` returns a dynamic object

Comment: @Silvermind I don't have any tool to decompile AutoMapper. What do you mean by `property.Name.StartsWith`? `p` is a `PropertyInfo`

Comment: @Marc My mistake, sorry.

Comment: @Marc what? No it doesn't. It returns an object of whatever type you specify.

Comment: It returns an object of type object. I will change dynamic for object

Comment: that's the definition of Map : `object Map(object source, object destination, Type sourceType, Type destinationType);`

Comment: @AndersonPimentel Thank you for the bounty!

Comment: @Marc You're welcome! I was curious about this one. Tried a lot of things but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your configuration as a separate profile, then add that profile to the mapper configuration.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic newObject = new NewObject();
        var objectToCopy = new ObjectToCopy();

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        mapper.Map(objectToCopy, newObject);
        // newObject.LU_Ignore = "Original value"
        // newObject.DoNotIgnore = "New value"
    }
}

class MyProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        ShouldMapProperty = p => !p.Name.StartsWith("LU"); // this is the correct way to get the property name
    }
}

class ObjectToCopy
{
    public string LU_Ignore { get; set; } = "New value";

    public string DoNotIgnore { get; set; } = "New value";
}


class NewObject
{
    public string LU_Ignore { get; set; } = "Original value";

    public string DoNotIgnore { get; set; } = "Original value";
}
```

Something seems goofy about how configurations are applied to the `Mapper` created form the `mapper.CreateMapper` call. I'm looking into it to see if I can find out more information and will update this answer if I find anything.

Comment: You are right. It works when you create it as a separate profile. That's weird. Thank you

Comment: Do you still need the ShouldMapField method call? When properties are modified, the ShouldMapField is still invoked on the backing field, so the code in the original post wouldn't behave as expected. I opted to not include it as it didn't seem to be what you were looking for, but I can edit my answer.

Comment: No it's not needed. I tried it only because `ShouldMapProperty` wasn't working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wont say that this is the best (performant or design-wise) approach, but this works:

```
public static class AutoExtensions {
    public static IMappingExpression Ignore(this IMappingExpression expression, Func<PropertyInfo, bool> filter) {
        foreach (var propertyName in expression
            .TypeMap
            .SourceType
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(filter)
            .Select(x=>x.Name))
        {
            expression.ForMember(propertyName, behaviour => behaviour.Ignore());
        }

        return expression;
    }
}
```

You can configure your mapper like this (for these sample classes):

```
public class Client {
    public string LUName { get; set; }
    public string Dno { get; set; } 
}

public class ClientDTO
{
    public string LUName { get; set; }
    public string Dno { get; set; } 
}
```

and test it out like this:

```
private static void ConfigAndTestMapper() {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>{
            cfg.CreateMap(typeof (Client), typeof (ClientDTO))
                .Ignore(x => x.Name.StartsWith("LU"));
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var result = mapper.Map<ClientDTO>(new Client() {LUName = "Name", Dno = "Dno"});

        var isIgnored = result.LUName == null;
    }
```

PS: this is also pretty "hackish" since it tries to map all kind of properties there (readonly/non-public, etc.) so take it with a grain of salt.